# Problems Installing rgeos and rgdal on Mac OS X High Sierra

Tags: r, anaconda, rgdal

I have looked at the multiple sources to figure out how to install `rgeos` and `rgdal` on Mac OS X High Sierra in a way that works with Anaconda Navigator. I mention Anaconda because I want to be able to build static project-specific, package environments to ensure that my projects work 6 months from now when the dependent packages change. I have successfully installed and used both `rgeos` and `rgdal` on a couple other computers but seem to be having issues on a new computer. I want to launch Shiny apps from Anaconda Navigator's RStudio. None of the solutions I found, listed below, worked:

- https://dyerlab.ces.vcu.edu/2015/03/31/install-rgeos-on-osx/
- https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/rgeos/rgeos.pdf
- http://tlocoh.r-forge.r-project.org/mac_rgeos_rgdal.html
- https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/r-rgdal

Based on the above sources and my slow progression through a series of error messages, I tried the following:

1. Install GDAL 2.2 Complete [30.0 MiB] 2018-3-10 from http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks. This installs GDAL, GEOS, PROJ, SQLite and UnixImageIO frameworks.

The above installed without an error message. But attempting to install rgeos gave an error message:

`configure: error: geos-config not found or not executable.`

Consequently, either the install failed and didn't notify me, or there is some type of `$PATH` issue (?). On a blog, someone suggested to do the following in response to the aforementioned issue:

2. `brew install geos`

The above completed successfully. So I went into RStudio and tried the following, which resolved the former error but produced a new one:

3. > install.packages("~/Downloads/rgeos_0.3-28.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")

   installing *source* package ‘rgeos’ ...
   configure: CC: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
   configure: CXX: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++
   configure: rgeos: 0.3-28
   checking for /usr/bin/svnversion... yes
   cat: inst/SVN_VERSION: No such file or directory
   configure: svn revision: 
   checking for geos-config... /usr/local/bin/geos-config
   checking geos-config usability... yes
   configure: GEOS version: 3.6.2
   checking geos version at least 3.2.0... yes
   checking geos-config clibs... yes
   checking geos_c.h  presence and usability... no
   configure: error: geos_c.h not found in standard or given locations.
   ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgeos’
   removing ‘/Users/aloha2018/anaconda2/lib/R/library/rgeos’
   Warning in install.packages :
     installation of package ‘/Users/aloha2018/Downloads/rgeos_0.3-28.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Any ideas on what to try next?

Naturally, I already tried in an RStudio application launched from Anaconda Navigator:

`install.packages("rgeos")`
`install.packages("rgdal")`

both from CRAN and from tar.gz. But it seems like it is unable to find a file called `geos_c.h`, which does indeed exist on my computer at:

`/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3B/Headers/geos_c.h`

Is there a way to tell RStudio to look in the directory containing that file so my `rgeos` and `rgdal` installations work? Are there other errors I should expect to encounter and if so, how do I avoid/resolve them?

I also tried in a Terminal window:

`conda install -c conda-forge r-rgdal`

but that fails after spending a long time attempting to "solve environment":

```
Andrews-MacBook-Pro:~ aloha2018$ conda install -c conda-forge r-rgdal 
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - r-rgdal
  - rstudio==1.1.423
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

So I try:

`conda r-rgdal`

But there is no output:

```
Andrews-MacBook-Pro:~ aloha2018$ conda info r-rgdal
Andrews-MacBook-Pro:~ aloha2018$
```

Comment: I have never been able to get `rgeos` or `rgdal` to work with conda. I think maybe they don't respect the Anaconda `$PATH` override.

Comment: I see. Any idea what to do? Do you think a solution would involve altering the .Renviron file? Ref: https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/r-startup.html#renviron

Comment: After installing GDAL and GES and the rest of that "Complete 2.2" package from http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks and doing none of the other stuff, I get rgdal and rgeos installed and loaded without difficulty from the R.app GUI. I'm wondering if the homebrew geos install screwed uo the PATH for your IDE?

Comment: @42- "After installing GDAL and GES and the rest of that "Complete 2.2" package", does this mean you did more than install "GDAL 2.2 Complete [30.0 MiB] 2018-3-10" ? I only installed that single package. But this is helpful info. Maybe it's also because I am launching RStudio from Anaconda?

Comment: That's all I installed but I meant to imply that PROJ4.1 and at least another were also installed. I'm not sure what it means to say that Rstudio is being launched from Anaconda. You should be able to extract the system environment setting from within Rstudio. Run: `Sys.getenv()` and run `?Starup` (in R) to get the name of files and the sequence of loading. I think RStudio depends on contents of `Renviron.site` or `Renviron`

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue. I first solved it by installing everything using conda using the following `environment.yml` configuration

```
name: london-crime-r
channels:
   - conda-forge
   - conda
dependencies:
   - gdal
   - geos
   - r-base
   - r-rcpp
   - r-irkernel
   - r-mass
   - r-dplyr
   - r-rgdal
   - r-rgeos
   - r-raster
   - rstudio
```

However, after updating `conda`, resolving dependencies did not finish within the 10 hours so I went the traditional route:

Use `brew` to install `geos` and `gdal`. It takes 40 minutes to build on my machine.

```sh
brew install geos gdal
```

Once that has been achieved, install `R` packages in this sequence.

```
install.packages('sp', type='source')

install.packages("rgeos", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org", type="source")
require(rgeos)

install.packages("rgdal", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org", type="source")
require(rgdal)
```

Subsequently, the packages below are ok with the plain `install`.

```
libraries <- c("rgdal",
               "rgeos",
               "raster",
               "spdep",
               "spatstat")
install.packages(libraries)
```